# Veracrypt cannot decrypt hard drive after moving to another system

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, truecrypt, veracrypt

I had a computer system with an SSD and a spinning hard disk drive. The OS was installed to the SSD unencrypted and my personal files were installed on the HDD. The HDD was encrypted using VeraCrypt as a device-hosted (non-system) volume, as opposed to a file-hosted volume.

Since then the the SSD has failed and I can longer boot the system. While I can live with the loss of the SSD, the HDD has important data which I really need to recover. I've connected it to another system via SATA. Windows can see the drive and I can assign it a drive letter. However, when I try to decrypt with VeraCrypt, I get the following message:

```
Operation failed due to one or more of the following:

 - Incorrect password.
 - Incorrect Volume PIM number.
 - Incorrect PRF (hash).
 - Not a valid volume.

Source: MountVolume:7763
```

I'm pretty sure the password is correct. I tried using the backup volume header via mount options, plus restoring the volume header via *Tools* -> *Restore Volume Header*, but neither option works. I don't have a rescue disk.

Any suggestions as what else I can try to do to recover the data?

Comment: Have you tried using the Veracrypt rescue disc? --> https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=VeraCrypt%20Rescue%20Disk

Comment: I don't have a rescue disk but I tried the 'Use backup header embedded in volume if available' option in the Mount Options, but this isn't working.

Comment: Without a rescue disk it is going to be extremly difficulty if not impossible to get your data decrypted.